# Reforming abnormal conditions to normal ones in Perl

Tags: regex, string, perl, replace, pattern-matching

I have a weird file that lists some conditions in an abnormal way. Some of the abnormalities that I'm stuck with are the following forms:

`bluh < blah < blip`, `bluh <= blah < blih`, `bluh < blah <= blih` and `bluh <= blah <= blih` (and same forms for `>` and `>=`).

(The abnormalities are not limited to this, but I'll try to handle the rest myself.) For now, assume that I am given with a $COND including multiple abnormalities (listed above). I want to reform all of the abnormalities to normal (perl looking) form.

For instance, I have:

`100 < r <= expression && 10 >= d > 1.3 && s >= 3`

and want to reform it to

`100 < r && r <= expression && 10 >= d && d > 1.3 && s >=3`

**NOTE:**

If it's too hard -which it shouldn't be- share your solution only for one abnormal condition. For example:

`10 >= d > 1.3` to `10 >= d && d > 1.3`

Comment: no need to worry about odd conditions like `3 <= L > 5`

Answer (score 4):

Need more examples to do this well, but based on the single example in your question, I think this will work:

```
open my $ABNORM, "<file.txt" or die $!;
my @lines = <$ABNORM>;
close $ABNORM or die $!;

foreach(@lines) {
    s/([>=<!]{1,2})\s*(\w+)\s*([>=<!]{1,2})/$1 $2 && $2 $3/g;
    print $_, "\n";
}
```

Comment: @ikegami did you test that edit that you made to my solution?  It doesn't work when I try it.

Comment: sweet. Keep here updated please with your efforts on more complicated cases.

Comment: @user3761870 if you have more complicated examples, please add them to your question and I'll test them.

Comment: @David, I didn't change its behaviour (except to silence four warnings). Bad test, or your original code also suffered from the problem.

Answer (score 1):

A relatively simple regex solution:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my $expr_re = qr{(?:[\w\s.]+?)};
my $op_re = qr{(?:[<>=]+)};

while (<DATA>) {
    chomp;

    s/$expr_re$op_re\K\s*(?=($expr_re)\s*$op_re)/ $1 && /g;

    print $_, "\n";
}

__DATA__
foo < bar < baz
foo <= bar < baz
foo < bar <= baz
foo <= bar <= baz
foo <= bar <= baz <= bazinga
100 < r <= expression && 10 >= d > 1.3 && s >= 3
```

Outputs:

```
foo < bar && bar < baz
foo <= bar && bar < baz
foo < bar && bar <= baz
foo <= bar && bar <= baz
foo <= bar && bar <= baz && baz <= bazinga
100 < r && r <= expression && 10 >= d && d > 1.3 && s >= 3
```

There are two known flaws with this logic

1. `A || B < C < D` is not the same thing as `A || B < C && C < D`.  Namely, there needs to be parenthesis around the expanded expression to maintain proper order of operations.  `A || (B < C && C < D)`
2. I don't attempt to distinguish between lower precedence operators: `and`, `or`, `xor`.

There are probably other flaws, but this can be a proof of concept at least.